# Wordpress and Javascript, whats wrong?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

i am making my own custom wordpress theme. And I am having a problem with javascript. I have writing code in the functions.php. All css is working, but I cant manage to make a toggle menu (for responsive purpoises). Maybe I am doing something wrong ? I copy my code from function.php at the bottom. P.s. i also created javascript.js for the code. But i can't figure whats the problem.

```
        function pirma_enqueue_styles(){
wp_enqueue_style('custom_s_s',trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'css/style.css');        wp_enqueue_style('javascript',trailingslashit(get_template_directory_uri()) . 'js/js.js');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'pirma_enqueue_styles');
```

Comment: You need to use `wp_enqueue_script` for your JS file, not `wp_enqueue_style`.

Answer (score 0):

If you created the resource file `javascript.js`, you simply enqueued the wrong script (namely `js/js.js`). Also look out for the correct path: You declared that the file is in the directory `js`.

Also - and more important in this case - to include scripts you need to use [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/), not `wp_enqueue_style()`.